# pygame drawing a filled rectangle overwrite border, but only sometimes?

Tags: python, pygame, draw, rect, class-variables

I have a class in my pygame program that extends sprite, and effectively gives collision and whatnot to a rectangle. The `__init__` of the class is as follows:

```
def __init__(self,topleft,size,label):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface(size)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.topleft = topleft
    self.image.fill([128,128,128])
    pygame.draw.rect(self.image, [200,200,200], self.rect, 5)
```

And this works great... for one rectangle. Problem is, after that rectangle, any others are solidly colored rectangles set to the fill color (128,128,128) instead of being a filled rectangle with a differently colored (200,200,200) border. I'm expecting this is some sort of issue with class variables as opposed to instance variables, but I'm unsure where the problem lies.

Comment: you are explicitly setting the fill color to a constant ... why would you expect different colors?

Comment: The fill is constant, but the rectangle's border is a _different_ constant. The problem is, for every rectangle beyond the first, the border is set to the fill color instead of it's intended value of 200,200,200

Comment: ok now I understand ...

Comment: If you use `self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,*size)` instead of `self.image.get_rect()`, do you get the same problem? All I can think is that the rect is being drawn in the wrong place, even though its topleft ought to be 0,0. (If you're applying that `topleft` argument to `self.rect` somewhere, then maybe the function is drawing the rect away from `self.image`'s origin?)

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to add in that line, I have self.rect.topleft = topleft before I fill the surface. I'll add that in on the OP.

Changing the way I get the rect isn't fixing the border either. I just did a quick experiment, I removed the fill and it looks like the second rectangle isn't being drawn at all. It's got a location and a rect, because I can still collide with it, but it's just not drawing the border at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The Rect argument in the draw function is *relative* to the position of the image. Since I had set its rect to its location on the screen, it was drawing the rectangle way offset from the corner. It worked on my first one only because it happened to start at [0,0]. Here is the fixed draw code:

```
pygame.draw.rect(self.image, [200,200,200],pygame.Rect([0,0],size), 5)
```